# TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many to many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am currently getting this error when making a POST request, and I am not sure what is causing it because I have not explicitly declared anything as a many-to-many relationship. What's also confusing me is that I don't have any object/relation called group, so why is it saying use groups.set()?

I am using nested serializers, as when creating a student I want it to create a user object underneath it.

I have attached an image of the GET request succeeding, as it shows the format in which data should be POST'ed

[image: GET Request]

Here is an image of the error I'm getting as well

[image: Error]

These are the two current relations in question that are giving me problems

***Users***(**id(PK)**, username, password, first_name, last_name, dob, role, email, house, comments)

***Students***(**id(PK)**, **user_id(FK)**, grade, enrollment_year)

Here is the serializer create method and the view's POST method

```
def create(self, validated_data):
     user_data = validated_data.pop('user')     
     user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
     student = Student.objects.create(**validated_data, user=user)     
     return student
```

```
def post(self, request):
""" Create new student """ 
serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data) 
if serializer.is_valid(): 
    serializer.save() 
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```